# React - Fetch in useEffect to check user database

Tags: fetch, create-react-app, use-effect

I'm stuck trying to find the best way to do a user search in the database and if there is mount the page, if there is no redirect to the root. This is the last thing I tried, but always redirect to root.

App.js

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" render={() => <Register />} />
            <Route path="/resetpassword" render={() => <ResetPassword />} />
            <Route path="/:username">
              <Middleware />
            </Route>
            <Route render={() => <Home />} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Middleware.js

```js
const Middleware = () => {
    const [exist, setExist] = useState(false);
    const { username } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        var isCancelled = false;

        async function fetch() {
            await datosFirebaseUsuario(username)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (!isCancelled) {
                        setExist(true)
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        fetch();

        return () => {isCancelled = true}
    }, [username])

    if (!exist) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Links />
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to use await fetch() to get the result you need on first look I may be wrong

Comment: I get the same result, redirect to root path :(

Comment: it may also be helpful to rename the function to another name, "fetch" is already taken in javascript, I will look for a solution in the mean time

Comment: I seed that the problem is the redirect. It is activated without waiting for the update of "exist". I guess I will have to place a loading or something similar